# Java Script RegExp

Tags: javascript

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/);
```

I using RegExp to check for unavailable characters of string. How can I add the space ' ' character to that?

Comment: `unavailable characters of string` what does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for special characters, then try `\W`

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/\W/);
```

This will match all special characters including space.

Answer (score 0):

\s for space character. See here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: Worked with \W, from the other comment, but thanks anyway!